# Writing a query to display the following result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are 3 tables:

Table A:

```
code    aname
------- ---------
1       A
2       B
3       C
```

Table B:

```
code        bname
----------- ----------
1           aaa
1           bbb
2           ccc
2           ddd
```

Table C:

```
code        cname
----------- ----------
1           xxx
1           yyy
1           zzz
2           www
```

We need to write a query that would display the following result:

```
code        aname      bname            cname
----------- ---------- ----------      ----------
1           A          aaa              xxx
1           A          bbb              yyy
1           A          NULL             zzz
2           B          ccc              www
2           B          ddd              NULL
3           C          NULL             NULL
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your current query and tell us what's wrong with it!

Comment: Do a `LET JOIN` b/w all the tables.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I strongly assume its `SQL Server` since OP's tag selection `SQL` and `Server` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to establish an ordering column of `TableB` and `TableC`, since it appears that the number of them is important. I'm going to use [CTEs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), which are supported by many systems, but you could do subqueries instead.

```
with tbb as (
  select
    *
    ,row_number() over (partition by code order by bname) nameorder
  from
    TableB
), tbc as (
  select
    *
    ,row_number() over (partition by code order by cname) nameorder
  form
    TableC
), mrg as (
  select
    coalesce(tbb.code, tbc.code) code
    ,bname
    ,cname
  from
    tbb
    full outer join tbc on
      tba.code = tbb.code
      and tba.nameorder = tbb.nameorder
)
select
  tba.code
  ,aname
  ,bname
  ,cname
from
  TableA tba
  left outer join mrg on tba.code = mrg.code
```

Comment: Thanks for the above query ..I had tried doing left join on all the tables but the NULL values were not showing up also had tried doing all possible joins and group by but still was stuck..Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a full `join` key, because you want lists in each column.  To get this, you need to use a `full outer join` and to generate ordering keys.  Note:  the final ordering within each column is arbitrary.

```
select coalesce(a.code, b.code, c.code) as code,
       a.aname, b.bname, c.cname
from (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by code order by code) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a full outer join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by code order by code) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on a.code = b.code and a.seqnum = b.seqnum full outer join
     (select c.*, row_number() over (partition by code order by code) as seqnum
      from c
     ) c
     on c.code in (a.code, b.code) and c.seqnum in (a.seqnum, b.seqnum)
```

Comment: While this is a functional query, I doubt the OP will grasp it, and when looking at his question, I would really question him *"What do you want to do at all ... ?"* Queries like this are interesting if you want to do SQL riddles, or student's examen or theoretical research. But it seems to me that the OP wanted to do something very simple, and therefore we should ask what he wanted to do at all. I am sure the solution he really needs is much simpler ....

Comment: BTW, that's the difference between a *programmer* and a *software engineer*: The *programmer* gets a question by a client, and does *exactly* what the client said. No questions. Even if the solution is totally complicated. He assumes the client is an IT specialist. The *software engineer* goes further and ask himself *"what does the client want at all?"* - And talks to the client, tries to understand him, and then finds a solid & simple solution.

Comment: @SQLPolice . . . Once again, I have no idea what your objections are to an answer that correctly addresses the OPs questions and is standard SQL.  You should save your diatribes for another forum, that is more appropriate for such comments.

Comment: While I appreciate your SQL knowledge which is really great and very useful, we should question what people **actually want to do with their solutions**. OK, computer science is a pleasure, but mostly, software is used for certain solutions. And this case here is an example where I am sure that the original problem should be reviewed. IMHO, that would be much more help than puzzling out a complicated query which the OP possibly will not understand at all.

Comment: Besides that, your query will only work with the sample data provided by the OP. If there is data with different codes and different gaps, then it will fail. I have no time right now, but I will prove this on Friday.